# How do i add adsense code in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, adsense

I want to add adsense code in chrome extension (manifest_version:2).

I have a popup.html page in which i have a dedicated  a block for ads:

```
<div id="adblock">
            <script type="text/javascript"><!--google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxx";/* Getfiles Chrome Extn Banner 468x60 */google_ad_slot = "xxxxxx"; google_ad_width = 468;google_ad_height = 60;//--></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
        </div>
```

But when it is executed it generates following error:

```
Refused to load the script 'http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js".
```

It is due to the new content security policy which prohibits inline javascript .

To overcome this i have tried to create that code in popup.js file

```
document.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {

                var x = chrome.extension.getViews({type:"popup"});
                rowOutput='<script type="text/javascript"><!--google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxx";/* Getfiles Chrome Extn Banner 468x60 */google_ad_slot = "xxxx"; google_ad_width = 468;google_ad_height = 60;//--></script><script type="text/javascript"src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>';
                if (x.length>0){

                  x[0].document.getElementById('adblock').innerHTML=rowOutput;
                 }
}, true);
```

When i reload the extension and click the extension icon the browser hangs and popup doesnot open.

Answer (score 1):

In manifest add this

```
"content_security_policy": "object-src 'unsafe-eval'; script-src 'unsafe-eval' https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com; connect-src *"
```

only https then add "s" 
change

> http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com

with

> https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com